# What is being returned and what is being taken in the function described by this documentation?

Tags: c++

I am looking at this documentation from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/variables_map.html

```
const variable_value & operator[](const std::string & name) const;
```

I am looking at this to evaluate the logic of a c++ project. You cannot return an array from a function in c++, so I am confused about what the square brackets are for preceding the parameter list. I am also confused about why there is a const after the trailing list.

Comment: This `operator` returns a `const` reference, not an array. Please search for **operator overloading**

Comment: This is a simple [overloaded subscript operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access).

Comment: The trailing `const` means this method doesn't modify anything inside.

Answer (score 1):

The trailing const means that the "this" parameter in the function is also const. The implication of this is that no class state can be mutated in this function, and that the function cannot call other non-const member functions.

The function signature itself is overloading the [] operator. The return type for the function is "const variable_value &". Overloading the [] operator allows you to index your class by whatever kind of indicies you'd like. Normally, [] is used by arrays to access elements (arr[1] == second element of array). With this overload, the class can be indexed with a string parameter (thatClass["SomeString"]).